# Library to house lists used to create dependent drop downs in InfoPath

Tags: list, infopath, library, dropdown

I am trying to create a dependent drop down list in a new InfoPath form.

The best way I found is to create lists in SharePoint and reference those with a filter option. I have created those lists under the "Lists" section.

Can I create a separate library to house all of my lists or do I need to create each list in the list section?

Ultimately, I don't want my functional lists to be seen by everyone. Is it easier to hide lists or libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply want to open SharePoint Designer and set the properties on the lists to be hidden and they won't show up in the UI.

The better option though is to leave them visible through the UI but alter the permissions appropriately so only a few select users have the ability to modify the contents where everyone else will have read permissions.

And no, there is no concept of a library of lists.